# Is there a bijective function that satisfies f(a*b) = f(b) * f(a)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G,*)$ be a group. Define a group $(G',*')$ as such that $G = G'$ and $$x*'y = y*x$$. Show that $(G',*')$ is isomorphic to (G,*).

I got to the point where $f(a *'b) = f(b * a)$. I know I have to find a bijective function $f$ from G to itself such that $f(b*a)=f(a)*f(b)$. I thought about identity function, but it works only if * is commutative. But it is unknown wether * is commutative or not. Any hint?

Comment: What is $(ab)^{-1}$?

Comment: @TokenToucan you mean inverse of a matrix ?

Comment: @JJW22 I'm pretty sure TokenToucan means the inverse of the group element $ab$, whatever the group elements may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction you're referencing is called the "opposite" of $G$.  You are right that the identity map will not work when $G$ is non-commutative.

Define $f:G \to G'$ by $f(a)=a^{-1}$.   Note that it does not matter if you consider $a^{-1}$ constructed in $G$ or $G'$ since the inverse axiom is symmetric/two-sided:  it's the same in either group.  At any rate, $f$ is clearly bijective.  We have $f(a*b) = (a*b)^{-1} = b^{-1}*a^{-1}=f(b)*f(a) = f(a) *' f(b)$, so $f$ is an iso.

Comment: Just wondering if it is universally true that (a∗b)^−1=b^−1∗a^−1 regardless of what * is? I am sure it has not been covered in my current class/

Comment: Yes, that is true in any group.  To prove it, you prove that $b^{-1}a^{-1}$ "acts like" the inverse to $ab$.  Uniqueness of inverses finishes it off.